# The ng-hide element appears for a while and then hide?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-hide

```
<div class="alert alert-warning" ng-hide="badges.length">      
    <strong>Empty!</strong> This Micro_organization has No badges.
</div>
<ul> 
  <li ng-repeat="badge in badges">{{ badge.title }}</li>
</ul>
```

even if badges are not empty, the message `Empty! This Micro_organization has No badges.` appears for a while.

Is there any solution so that the message will only show if badges is empty?

Comment: how do u get data for `badges`,  using a ajax call ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak).

Comment: @K.Toress yes.. some thing like `$resource('/ng/badges/');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using ajax request to get the data then `badges` will `undefined` untill ajax call return the data.

untill the data receive `badges.length` will stay `undefined` then then `ng-hide="badges.length"` will result in something `ng-hide="false"` thats may be the case of partially apearing the div

--solution--

if you declare `$scope.badge` before u get the `resource`  data remove that declaration.  declare `$scope.badge` only after the `resource` call. and use

```
 <div class="alert alert-warning" ng-hide="badges.length != 0">..
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1wSIDasJPtjdJQayi9CS?p=preview)

Comment: `ng-hide="badges.length != 0"` solves the problem...  thanks .. i don't know how,,

Answer (score 0):

Before `badges` is loaded, the variable is undefined. You can work around this problem by changing the `ng-hide` expression to ensure `badges` exists.

```
ng-hide="!badges || badges.length"
```